# Removing (not searching for!) unused CSS selectors based on Dust-Me

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Dust-Me(http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/) did a great job identifying unused CSS selectors, but now I need to remove them. Dust-Me generates a .CSV enumerating those selectors, but the tricky part is to actually remove them. I've got 1200 unused selectors and having those removed by hand will drive me nuts. Is there any way to automize the deletion process? Or is there any other application which can delete the unused CSS / regenerate the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Test [CSS Usage](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/css-usage/) Firefox extension (requires FireBug).
It does the same work as Dust-Me and provides clean files.
Unfortunately, these tools are not very precise... Keep a backup!

Comment: -1: This does not provide clean files, it adds UNUSED before any CSS selector that is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ReduceCSS](http://www.reducecss.com/), I think it's a tool that does this. Identifies unused CSS selectors and keeps clean files.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for CSS Usage Firefox/Firebug extension. https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/css-usage/

as for the comment above by jperelli:
You can use a tool that is able to do a find/replace based upon regular expressions to delete only the selectors marked with "UNUSED".

I used Grant Skinners excellent regexr (http://www.regexr.com/) to come up with an expression:

UNUSED([\s\S][^}]*})

Tools that can use this method include for example notepad++ or Netbeans.

Hope that helps,

Sebastian

Comment: I can't get this to work with notepad++. I keep getting "invalid regular expression." I have "regular expressions" selected. Any suggestions?